# python function says " no attribute in function"

Tags: python, function, attributes

I am running below proecedure to get some values so that i use those values later in main program globally

```
import requests
import json
import sys

client= 'test'


def get_path(client):
    
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Vault-Token': get_token()}
    URL='https://xxxxxxxx.xxx/v1/'+'ab/li/'+client
    response=requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
    jout = json.loads(response.text)
    azure_path=jout['data']['account_id']
    get_path.tenant_id=jout['data']['tenant_id']
    return azure_path
    
    
tenant = ('tenant is :' + get_path(client).tenant_id)
print(tenant)
```

but its erroring saying there is no attribute

```
  tenant = ('tanant is :' + get_path.tenant_id(client))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tenant_id'
```

I am sure it has value when i print variable called `jout` it does have tenant id

**EDIT 1: Solved it by below**

```
    import requests
    import json
    import sys
    
    client= 'test'
    tenant_var = None
    
    def get_path(client):
        global tenant_var
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Vault-Token': get_token()}
        URL='https://xxxxxxxx.xxx/v1/'+'ab/li/'+client
        response=requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
        jout = json.loads(response.text)
        azure_path=jout['data']['account_id']
        tenant_var=jout['data']['tenant_id']
        return azure_path
        
    tenant = ('tenant is :' + tenant_var)
    print(tenant)
```

Comment: `get_path().tenant_id`

Comment: I suggest:     
    azure_path=jout['data']['account_id']
    tenant_id=jout['data']['tenant_id']
    return azure_path, tenant_id

azure, tenant_id = get_path(client)
tenant = ('tenant is :' + tenant_id())

Comment: still same error. huh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using global variable deceleration

```
    import requests
    import json
    import sys
    
    client= 'test'
    tenant_var = None
    
    def get_path(client):
        global tenant_var
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Vault-Token': get_token()}
        URL='https://xxxxxxxx.xxx/v1/'+'ab/li/'+client
        response=requests.get(URL,headers=headers)
        jout = json.loads(response.text)
        azure_path=jout['data']['account_id']
        tenant_var=jout['data']['tenant_id']
        return azure_path
        
    tenant = ('tenant is :' + tenant_var)
    print(tenant)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your function, you are setting `tenant_id` as attribute of your function object `get_path`... it's a rather strange way of coding.

To make this work, you can adapt the following snippet:

```
def get_path(arg):
    get_path.tenant_id = '123' + arg
    return 'something else'

# get the function object
myfunction = get_path

# call the function
myfunction('myargument')

# consume the function object attribute
tenant = ('tenant is :' + myfunction.tenant_id)
```

Or the better way: as suggested in the comments, return the `tenant_id` as part of a tuple in the return value of your function.

Comment: solved it by declaring tenant_id as global variable.. then inside def mentioned that i am going to use that variable and returned one by one (not as tuple), becuase i was forming on url so tuple did not help..thanks for suggestion